# Gossip the truth and gossip the falsity

Tags: single-word-requests

Are there two verbs in English with the additional details in their meaning included:

1. to gossip true statements about somebody,
2. to gossip false statements about somebody?

Comment: It depends on what you mean about gossip. It could mean repeating salacious details about other people. Or it could be repeating salacious details of questionable veracity. Are either of those what you mean by 'gossip'?

Comment: You are inventing a new use of the verb *gossip*, as far as I know: as a **transitive** verb.  Nothing wrong with such invention (in my book), but please be aware that it is invention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for gossiping false statements, **slander** or **libel** might fit.

> - slander - "to make a false spoken statement that causes people to have a bad opinion of someone" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slander)
> - libel - "to write and publish a false statement that causes people to have a bad opinion of (someone)" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/libel?show=0&t=1418774995)
> - backbite - "to say mean or spiteful things about someone who is not present."

The problem with these verbs is that the false statements are always spiteful.

for gossiping true statements, to "advertise" someone's qualities or flaws.

Comment: But sometimes even true statements can be spiteful, is there a word for gossiping about somebody's true negative qualities, flaws, sins or embarrassing events?

Comment: @dt1510 That's true. False statements can be words of praise. Likewise, true statements can be about flaws or weakness in character. I know no specific word for each situation.

Answer (score 3):

Verbs:

**Slander** or **libel** imply false gossip (credit to @Centaurus for yesterday's answer)

**Tattle** implies "true" gossip